# XML file parsing in oracle database

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have one xml file named `abc.xml` in path `c:/error_log/abc.xml.`

I want to insert the content of this file in one table `"employee"` in oracle database through procedure.

can you help me with the procedure how to read xml file in oracle database.

Comment: Hi better if  you  use sql loader instead of procedure.

Comment: Using procedure call sql loader